# Why Arduino code with arduPi library in Raspberry Pi is not working?

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run my code that made for `Arduino Uno` into my `Raspberry Pi 3` having a shield connection bridge made by [Cooking Hacks](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge). The code is (***led.cpp***):

```
#include "arduPi.h"


int LED = 9;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}

int main (){
    setup();
    while(1){
        loop();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I have enabled **UART** (`/boot/config.txt` and `/boot/cmdline.txt` have been edited) according to the documentation. I thought connection bridge is not working. Anyway, to make sure that the shield is working fine, I made a python script as follows with proper pin config according to the [arduPi pin config](https://github.com/lavirott/arduPi/blob/master/arduPi/arduPi.cpp#L1467) (***led.py***):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
from time import sleep 

LED = 22

GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT) 

while True: 
    GPIO.output(LED, True) 
    sleep(1) 
    GPIO.output(LED, False) 
    sleep(1)
```

In this case python script works fine without any change in physical (pin) configuration (meaning that pin 9 on Arduino is equivalent to pin 22 on Raspberry Pi). I mean the connection bridge is also working well. So, what did I made wrong with the ***led.cpp*** while the ***led.py*** is fine?

***UPDATE:***

I have activated pin `GPIO 4` (`digital pin 3` or `BCM 23`) as instructed in [Cooking Hacks](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge) and [arduPi instruction page](https://github.com/lavirott/arduPi), and then real config with:

```
gpio mode 4 OUT
gpio write 4 1
gpio readall
```

I got:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT5 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT5 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3B--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

To verify the arduPi library I wrote a program to read digital pin 2-9 which looks like (***pin_reader.cpp***):

```
#include "arduPi.h"


void setup()
{
    printf("Ard\tRPi\tVal\n");

    for(int pin = 2; pin <= 9; pin++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", pin, raspberryPinNumber(pin), digitalRead(pin));
        delay(1000);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void loop()
{
    //delay(5000);
}

int main (){
    setup();
    while(1){
        loop();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

which gives me:

```
Ard RPi Val
2   18  0
3   23  0
4   24  1
5   25  1
6   4   0
7   17  1
8   27  1
9   22  0
```

In the previous step, I applied 1 (HIGH) at `GPIO 4` (`digital pin 3` or `BCM 23`) which is verified with `gpio readall` or `gpio read 4` (which gives `1` as expected). However, I am getting `0` instead of `1` with `digitalRead` from ardupi. **Why digitalRead is giving values other than expected?**

Comment: Are you able to run any of the ardupi examples?

Comment: @NathanWride Not at all.

Comment: Well that at least rules out anything you've done code-wise. Are you able to execute the commands listed under note? https://github.com/lavirott/arduPi